metadata extension interface - invalid account data for instruction on TlvStateMut::unpack
I'm trying to test out the metadata extension, and am just copying the interface and example that can be found here https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/a66f323de3e38116e2eeb11a1012d60f43229de5/token-metadata/interface/src/state.rs.
The metadata pointer initialise instruction works fine, the mint is created, but when i come to write the metadata I get an "invalid account data":
let token_metadata = state::TokenMetadata {
            name: "test name".to_string(),
            symbol: "test".to_string(),
            uri: "test.com".to_string(),
            update_authority: *funding_account_info.key,
            mint: *token_mint_account_info.key,
            ..Default::default()
        };

        let instance_size = get_instance_packed_len(&token_metadata)?;
        // allocate a TLV entry for the space and write it in
        let mut buffer = token_mint_account_info.try_borrow_mut_data()?;
        let mut state = TlvStateMut::unpack(&mut buffer)?;

The last line here triggers the error.  Does anyone know what could be going wrong? The mint has been initialised using spl_token_2022::instruction::initialize_mint2 and i've minted the nft at this point to an ATA.
Thanks for any help you can provide!

You can use the instructions from the spl crate:
You can init the meta data like this:
    let init_token_meta_data_ix = 
    &spl_token_metadata_interface::instruction::initialize(
        &spl_token_2022::id(),
        ctx.accounts.mint.key,
        ctx.accounts.nft_authority.to_account_info().key,
        ctx.accounts.mint.key,
        ctx.accounts.nft_authority.to_account_info().key,
        "Beaver".to_string(),
        "BVA".to_string(),
        "https://arweave.net/MHK3Iopy0GgvDoM7LkkiAdg7pQqExuuWvedApCnzfj0".to_string(),
    );

 invoke_signed(
        init_token_meta_data_ix,
        &[ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info().clone(), ctx.accounts.nft_authority.to_account_info().clone()],
        signer,
    )?;

and update fields like this:
// Update the metadata account with an additional metadata field in this case the player level
    invoke_signed(
        &spl_token_metadata_interface::instruction::update_field(
            &spl_token_2022::id(),
            ctx.accounts.mint.key,
            ctx.accounts.nft_authority.to_account_info().key,
            spl_token_metadata_interface::state::Field::Key("level".to_string()),
            "1".to_string(),
        ),
        &[
            ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info().clone(),
            ctx.accounts.nft_authority.to_account_info().clone(),
        ],
        signer
    )?;

Here you can find a full example on how to create an extension meta data NFT in anchor:
https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/blob/main/tokens/token-2022/nft-meta-data-pointer/anchor/program/programs/extension_nft/src/instructions/mint_nft.rs

Thanks, just using the interface directly worked for some reason, not sure what i was doing wrong but i guess it doesn't matter!
